# How to find asymtotic run time of this method?

Tags: java, methods, time

I was asked to write this method and then give the asymptotic run time in terms of the size of the array. Could someone explain to me how this is done?

```
public int doSomething(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (nums[i] > nums[j])
                count++;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you know so far about asymptotic runtime? It's a subject that could easily be a full chapter or more; this question is too broad for SO's format as written, since you're basically asking for that chapter. Please give this a try and ask more specific questions.

Comment: You're aware that there's something missing after the `if`, right?

Comment: I know that they have categories, like linear. They represent how many functions the method has to do in order to see how easy it will be to run. As far as knowing how to find this, I haven't a clue.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it with count++;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem size N is the length of nums.

The way to decide asymptotic runtime from code where there are only for-statements is pretty straightforward.

Asymptotic runtimes are described by traditional notation like

```
O(N)
```

Which is one simple for-statement. We need to process the input elements only once.

Nested for-statements like you have means we need to check the value of each nums more than once.

You are repeating N times in the outer loop. You are repeating a number of times dependent on N in the inner loop.

Also how do you print a triangle like

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

The number of elements in the triangle is proportional to N²

Answer (score 1):

Well **run time** is usually how many steps you have to do.

**Asymptotic run time** is almost the same, but you can do some "magic" to simplify your result.

In your case you have cycle `for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)` which does `nums.length` steps. And in every step, you do `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`.

Well at first, you do only 1, then you do 2 steps, than 3 steps etc.

**Run time** is `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + .... + n`, using summation of series you get : `n*(n+1)/2`

**Asymptotic run time** is based on some rules. In our case, you can get rid off constants, only `n` is important, therefore `n*(n+1)/2 = Theta(n*(n)) = Theta(n^2)`

Result : `n^2`

Comment: I hate it when people write tings like `n*(n+1)/2 = Theta(n^2)` it is a very confusing abuse of the notation. `n*(n+1)/2` is an instance of `Theta(n^2)`, but by no means are they _equal_. As written, however, it is as absurd as `Integer.valueOf(n*(n+1)/2) == Integer.valueOf(n*n).class`.

Comment: @AJMansfield - actually you are wrong, both syntaxes are correct.

Comment: @libik Theta(anything) or Omega(anything) or O(anything) are _classes_. If we allow any member of the class to be equal to the class as a whole ,we can prove a whole slew of paradoxes. For example: `n+1 = O(n)`, `n+2 = O(n)`, therefore `n+1 = n+2`, and therefore `1 = 2`.

Comment: @AJMansfield - not, you cant abuse it like this :). But maybe some relevant source would be nice, every single one known to me does not make difference between "be element of" and "is equal" for asymptotic notations.

Comment: @libik There is a comprehensive discussion of this on [math.se], specifically http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86076/what-are-the-rules-for-equals-signs-with-big-o-and-little-o.